# How to add the data from tableview to sql

Tags: iphone

I am making an application. On one of the tab I have used tableview on which I am adding the local notifications timing by using time picker. I am also using sql database in my app. Now I want the timing which I have added in the table view must be store in database so that I can retrieve it on another tab. How Can I do this implementation. Please If anyone know it. Give me some solutions.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to receive the data in an other tab I think storing in mysql is a bit overkill.
What don't you use a shared object that will be used by both tables?

An other simple option will be to store the data in NSUserDefaults

```
//create an array of all the data in the table view.
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:array forKey:@"table data"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And in the next tab

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *array = [defaults objectForKey@"table data"];
//pass the array to the table view.
```

But that really depends on how much data you store and do you need it to be saved when the app is closed.

But the best solution in my opinion  will be to use core data.

GOOD Luck

Comment: I want to restore it firt in sql then it must be retrive from database and I can display these all values any time at any tab.